# Which beta distribution(s) has a variance `V` and a skew `S`?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, beta-function

Let `X` be a beta distributed random variable with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, variance `V` and skew `S`.

Is it possible that several different sets of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same variance and skew? Intuitively, I expect the answer to be "No"

How can I find the set of parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that yield that distribution to have a variance of `V` and a skew of `S`?

The solution should come from resolving the following system of equation but for some reason I failed to do so.

$$V = \frac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}$$
$$S = \frac{2(\beta-\alpha)\sqrt{\alpha+\beta+1}}{(\alpha + \beta + 2)\sqrt{\alpha \beta}}$$

Comment: The change of variables $x=\alpha+\beta+1$ and $y=\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)^{-2}$ yields the conditions $y=Vx$ and $$S^2V(x+1)^2+16Vx=4,$$ which can be readily solved in terms of $(x,y)$. This in turn yields $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ and the sign of $S$ determines which of these is $\alpha$ and which is $\beta$.

Comment: That works indeed. There is no good looking solution though. You can develop your comment as an answer if you want.  Thank you